# What is wrong with this Windows Metro Javascript navigation?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro

I'm creating a Windows Metro app that has ListViews as the main element on every page.  I've run into an issue navigating between pages, specifically navigating too fast: clicking on a ListView item on one page to go to another, then clicking back on the new page.  When I do this too fast, I get this:

```
Exception was thrown but not handled in user code at line 20, column 13 in ms-appx://01c489fc-0e20-415d-ad4b-2895b4bc6e90/pages/groupedItems/groupedItems.js

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'cloneNode' of undefined or null reference

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

What does this mean?  And are there any techniques that will keep this exception at bay and allow quick navigation?

Here's the code that errors:

```
function multisizeItemTemplateRenderer(itemPromise)
{
    return itemPromise.then(function (currentItem)
    {
        var content;

    // Grab the default item template used on the groupeditems page.
    content = document.getElementById('multiTemplate');

    /*************************
     This line is where it fails:
     *************************/
    var result = content.cloneNode(true);

    // Change the CSS class of the item depending on the group, then set the size in CSS.
    switch (currentItem.groupKey)
    {
        case "1":
            {
                // Decides which item to resize based on items index
                if (currentItem.index == 0 || currentItem.index == 1)
                {
                    result.className = "largeitemtemplate"
                }

                else
                {
                    result.className = "mediumitemtemplate"
                }
                break;
            }

        default:
            {
                result.className = "smallitemtemplate"
            }
    }
    // Because we used a WinJS template, we need to strip off some attributes 
    // for it to render.
    result.attributes.removeNamedItem("data-win-control");
    result.attributes.removeNamedItem("style");
    result.style.overflow = "hidden";

    /************************
     If this try catch isn't here, a RuntimeException occurs during quick navigation.
     ************************/
    try{
        result.getElementsByClassName("item-image")[0].src = currentItem.data.backgroundImage;
        result.getElementsByClassName("item-title")[0].textContent = currentItem.data.title;
    } catch (exception) {
        console.log(exception.name +  ": " + exception.message);
    }
    return result;
});
}
```

Comment: You should post the code that caused the error. Otherwise the best answer I can give is that you tried to access `.cloneNode` property of  `undefined` or `null`

Comment: Ok, I think I posted the issue code.

Comment: You are doing `document.getElementById('multiTemplate');` which returns `null` because the element was not found. In browser scripting, this means the code is ran before the DOM is ready or the element simply doesn't exist with this id.

Comment: @Esailija so how do I ensure the DOM is ready?  Should I also post the function that initializes my layout?

Comment: Use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868490.aspx  to initialize your app. Here's more tips about that but more Metro centric http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781221.aspx

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I'll try to get that DOMContentLoaded working, then.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a lot of elements in your ListView. And not waiting for the whole page will render completely. Just try to wait a little bit more before you click on anything in this view. Bug will disappear :)
After your click the new rendering process is starting and object "document" is changed to new one. Current renderer access this new document which has another structure and doesn't contain element with id='multiTemplate'. So document.getElementById('multiTemplate') returns null.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there's a way to cancel/not allow the elements to be updated after leaving the page?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this MSDN tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh972605.aspx) will help:

```
// Because we used a WinJS template, we need to strip off some attributes 
// for it to render.
result.attributes.removeNamedItem("data-win-control");
result.attributes.removeNamedItem("style");
result.style.overflow = "hidden";

// Because we're doing the rendering, we need to put the data into the item.
// We can't use databinding.
return result;
```